# How to use custom offline map in iOS app

Tags: ios, maps, geospatial, offline, adobe-illustrator

I'm developing an iPhone offline map application. I've illustrator map georeferenced (using mapublisher), have geodatabase (http://goo.gl/isw6IP) and parking data (shp/csv).

**Requirements:**

- The map should Pan, Pinch & zoom.
- Search addresses and parking (addresses have alternate names too) on map.
- Routing/Navigate to parking/address.
- GPS Positioning.
- App will work offline without internet connection once installed.

**Questions:**

1. In which formate I should export the illustrator map, geodatabase & parking data to be used in a iOS app.
2. Which iOS offline maps SDK is recommened for above requirements.

Few iOS SDKs like Route-ME, MapBox, Alpstein, Altus, Skobbler, cloudmade, ArcGis iOS SDK, nutiteq etc are using OSM data or their own hosted MAP data but I want to use my own illustrator map and all data will be available local for offline use.

I've search alot but could not find any concreat solution. Few links in my research.

- http://goo.gl/m9Lp1w
- http://goo.gl/IMKF4p
- http://goo.gl/gsrv5Q
- http://goo.gl/J4Ne5y
- https://goo.gl/1wP29H

Same question (similar to what I need) was asked long time ago but without any answer

- http://goo.gl/knoA1C

Answer (score 2):

1:
In my opinion, OpenStreetMap is the best one for all-around purposes such as the ones you mentionned: addresses, parkings, routing, maps.

You can answer all requirements with that format. Depending on your project, you may better transform your data in a specific format for each requirement.

2:
You'll probably have to use a few components to match all requirements :

> The map should Pan, Pinch & zoom.

Any of the SDK listed will do it.

> Search addresses and parking (addresses have alternate names too) on map.

You can query a local database then create markers.

> Routing/Navigate to parking/address.

I would recommend [GraphHopper](https://graphhopper.com/)

> GPS Positioning.

It can be done manually using CLLocationManager. Create a marker (according to the chosen SDK) then update it's coordinates.

> App will work offline without internet connection once installed.

That's the main requirement. You have to chose between vector and raster first, then pick the SDK. You'll probably have to make a few transformation here.